# Jasper Report Print Custom Objects in Arraylist

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am passing a List as paramter to Jasper as following.

```
Map<String, Object> model=new HashMap<>();
  List<CustomObject> issues=new ArrayList<>();
            issues.add(new CustomObject(1,"AIRPORT Services","XYZ","asdfa","asdf","asddf"));
            issues.add(new CustomObject(1,"AIRPORT Services","XYZ","asdfa","asdf","asddf"));
            model.put("issues",issues);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, model, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

Now I am able to retrieve issuesList in jasper but I can't retrieve value inside CustomObject.

Following works and prints reference of CustomObject iterated using following

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{list}.get($V{ROW_INDEX})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

This throws exception when I want to access value of field inside Custom Object such as

`<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{list}.get($V{ROW_INDEX}).getCustomMethod()]]>`

Exception:

```
Exception obtained is: The method getCustomMethod() is undefined for the type Object value = ((java.util.List)parameter_list.getValue()).get(((java.lang.Integer)variable_ROW_INDEX.getValue())).getCustomMethod(); //$JR_EXPR_ID=0$
```

With Help of Mike Answer at [Print an arraylist content with JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063386/print-an-arraylist-content-with-jasperreports)
 I have iterated my Arraylist in jasper. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know jasper but this error `Exception obtained is: The method getCustomMethod() is undefined for the type Object value`gives me the impression that the declared type of the instances get from the List is not `CustomObject` but just `Object`. Try to find a way to cast  them to `CustomObject`.

Comment: you are right This worked for me when I type cast inside JRXML as

Comment: Great :) Don't hesitate to write an answer and to accept it. It could help others.

Comment: thanks david Just done. Request you to please vote for this.

Comment: You are welcome. You should write an answer rather than editing the question :) Just post an answer and move the solution in it.

Comment: It is almost good. Just the text should not be quoted. I will edit to show you.

Comment: and you can also accept your answer as it has solved your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me when I just cast from `Object` to `CustomObject` like as
follow

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[((com.custom.CustomObject)$P{flightIssues}.get($V{ROW_INDEX})).getCustomeMethod()]]></textFieldExpression>
```